# Dynamically assign unique id from var value in Javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my program, I use javascript to generate a table which is then appended to the html document:

```
var html = "<table>";
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    html += "<tr>";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        html += "<td class=\"covered\"><input type=\"image\" src=\"imageURL.com"/></td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";
$(".gameboard").append(html);
```

I want each of the input elements to have a unique ID -- specifically a number.  I was hoping to have a variable that is initialized to 1, which gets incremented each time a TD element is created.  The value of this variable would be used as the input element ID.  I haven't found any way to do this specifically.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use UserId+indexId to usniquely define the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `global variable` let `count` and `increment` it in `inner loop`, like,

```
var html = "<table>";
var count=1;// use this variable in inner for loop and increment it by 1
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    html += "<tr>";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
        html += "<td class=\"covered\">\
                  <input id='"+(count++)+"' type=\"image\" src=\"imageURL.com\"/>\
                </td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";
$(".gameboard").append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var html = "<table>";
var index=0;

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
html += "<tr>";

for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
{
    html += "<td class=\"covered\"><input id='img"+(index++)+"' type=\"image\" src=\"imageURL.com"/></td>";
}
html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";
 $(".gameboard").append(html);
```

Comment: This code will still not work... the syntax highlighting is a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
html += "<td id='td-" + c +"'class=\"covered\"><input value='td-" + c +"' type=\"image\" src=\"imageURL.com"/></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 var ID= new Date().getTime();
```